# Sorting array in shell using awk

Tags: arrays, shell, sorting, unix, awk

I need to sort this file in descending order avoiding duplicates

```
Bob 5 404
Mike 3 404
Bob 19 404
Bob 78 404
Mike 93 404
Joe 7 404
```

So my result should be

```
Bob 102
Mike 96
Joe 7
```

What I have now is this

```
awk '{if($3 == 404) arr[$1]+=$2}END{for(i in arr)print i, arr[i]}' file
```

I know that there are `sort -d` but how I need to use it in awk?

**UPDATE**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=" "}{if($9 == 404) arr[$1]+=1}END{for(i in arr) print arr[i] | sort -k2nr }' input > output
```

I get this result

```
sh: 0:  not found
```

And my output file is now empty.

Comment: are the unique keys relatively 'finite'?

Comment: if you use `gawk` you have access to the `asort()` function.

Comment: That's not just sorting. You are aggregating the records with duplicate keys, not avoiding them.

Comment: The  `BEGIN{FS=" "}` is not necessary. You need to replace the `+=1` with `+=$2`.  Pipe the output to `sort -k2nr` to sort in reverse numeric order.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Good advice, but to ensure that sorting occurs _only_ by the 2nd column (though it doesn't make a difference in _this_ case), it should be `-k2,2nr`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks! but I updated the code, but I don't get expected results. In fact I get this: sh: 0:  not found

Comment: I mean `awk '{...}' | sort -k2nr`; if you want to 'print' to the command, then `print ... | "sort -k2nr"` in the `awk` script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Reuben L.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29830226/45375) contains the right pointers, but doesn't spell out the full solutions:

---

The **POSIX-compliant solution** spelled out:

You need to *pipe* the output from `awk` to the `sort` utility, *outside* of `awk`:

```
awk '{ if($3 == 404) arr[$1]+=$2 } END{ for (i in arr) print i, arr[i] }' input |
  sort -rn -k2,2 > output
```

Note the specifics of the `sort` command:

- `-r` performs *reverse* sorting
- `-n` performs *numeric* sorting
- `-k2,2` sorts by the 2nd whitespace-separated field *only*

  - by contrast, only specifying `-k2` would sort *starting* from the 2nd field *through the remainder of the line* - doesn't make a difference here, since the 2nd field is the *last* field, but it's an important distinction in general.

Note that there's really no benefit to using the nonstandard `-V` option to get numeric sorting, as `-n` will do just fine; `-V`'s true purpose is to perform *version-number* sorting.

<sup>Note that you *could* include the `sort` command *inside* your `awk` script - `for(i in arr)print i, arr[i] | "sort -nr -k2,2"` - note the `"` around the `sort` command - but there's *little benefit to doing so*.</sup>

---

The ***GNU* `awk` `asort()` solution** spelled out:

```
gawk '
  { if ($3 == 404) arr[$1]+=$2 } # build array
  END{
    for (k in arr) { amap[arr[k]] = k }   # create value-to-key(!) map
    asort(arr, asorted, "@val_num_desc")  # sort values numerically, in descending order
    # print in sort order
    for (i=1; i<=length(asorted); ++i) print amap[asorted[i]], asorted[i]
  }
' input > output
```

As you can see, this *complicates* the solution, because *2 extra arrays* must be created:

- `for (k in arr) { amap[arr[k]] = k }` creates the "inverse" of the original array in `amap`: it uses the *values* of the original array as *keys* and the corresponding *keys* as the *values*.
- `asort(arr, asorted, "@val_num_desc")` then sorts the original array by its *values* in descending, numerical order (`"@val_num_desc"`) and stores the result in new array `asorted`.

  - Note that the original *keys* are *lost* in the process: `asorted` keys are now numerical indices reflecting the sort order.
- `for (i=1; i<=length(asorted); ++i) print amap[asorted[i]], asorted[i]` then enumerates `asorted` by sequential numerical index, which yields the desired sort order; `amap[asorted[i]]` returns the matching key (e.g., `Bob`) from the original array for the value at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions:

1. Use `gawk` and the built-in `asort()` and `asorti()` functions
2. Pipe the output of your awk command to `sort -k2 -Vr`. This will sort descending by the second column.

*note: the `-V` flag is non-standard and is available for GNU `sort`. credits to Jonathan Leffler*

Comment: It would need to be `-k2n` for numeric sorting; otherwise, 9 will appear before 89.

Comment: Oh; hmm...I suppose so.  It's not a standard option -- you should point out that it will only work with GNU `sort` (it won't work with BSD/Mac OS X `sort`, for example).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Curiously, the _OSX_ `sort` utility _is_ GNU `sort` - it's  just _too old_ to support `-V` (as of OSX 10.10, it's version `5.93`(!), whereas the version on Ubuntu 14.04, for instance, is `8.21`). By contrast, the true _BSD_ version of `sort` _does_ implement `-V`, as of at least `2.3` (e.g., on FreeBSD 10).